# State Management for navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Im trying to use state management to modify my app and make it more generic. basicaly my app is react web app embedded with tableau dashboards, i need that specific routes (which hold specific dashboards) will be populated in the app through reading a json from the backend which specifies the project we want.

i need it in two ways:

UI project switch which lets me switch between projects
through the JWT which the front side recieves from a login attempt (upon sucsess)
i figured the only state needs managing is the navigation bar and its data, ill render the relevant paths and thus enable only the relevant dashboards by project/user.

this is the code for my navbar:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";
import Persona from "./Icons/Persona.svg";
import Logout from "./Icons/Logout.svg";
//someting





//Navbar function
function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Operational Overview');
  const location = useLocation();
  

  

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
    
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
     return true; 
    } )
    


  };

  const userConfigPageTitle = (path) => {
    setPageName("User Information");

  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location] ); 
  

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="hamburger" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>

          <div className="criminal-records">Elecciones Guatemala |</div> 
          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{pageName}</h1></div>

          <>
          <div><img className="userIcon" src={Persona} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="userButton">User123#</div>
          </>

          <Link to='/' className="logout-button">
          <div><img className="logoutIcon" src={Logout} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="logoutButton">Logout</div> 
          </Link>
          
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
          
            </li>
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                  <span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span><span className="navbutton-text" >{item.title}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

and this is NavbarData:

```
import React from 'react'



import startpageIcon from './Icons/startpage.svg';
import performance from './Icons/performance.svg';
import bars from './Icons/bars.svg';
import simulation from './Icons/simulation.svg';
import fraud from './Icons/fraud.svg';
import deployForNow from './Icons/Profiles.svg';
import Planning from './Icons/plan.svg';
import deployment from './Icons/layer1.svg';
import barswithperson from './Icons/barswithperson.svg'





export const NavbarData = [
    {
        title: 'Simulación',
        path: '/monitoringoverview',
        icon: <img  src={simulation} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    },
    {
        title: "Empadronados",
        path: "/performancequality",
        icon: <img src={barswithperson} alt="" />,
        cName: 'nav-text'
    }


]
```

so basically all i need is to connect the dropdown switcher to change the json structured data inside NavbarData, and define each of these variations as state. So since this is quite a simple state managing task i want to use React Context to solve it, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using React Context to control the navigation bar's status :

§ To define the context and its initial state, create a file named NavbarContext.js.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const NavbarContext = createContext();

export const NavbarProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [navbarData, setNavbarData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <NavbarContext.Provider value={{ navbarData, setNavbarData }}>
      {children}
    </NavbarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

§ Surround your application or the targeted area within your application using the NavbarProvider component, which should be done in your main file (i.e., App.js).

```
import { NavbarProvider } from "./NavbarContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <NavbarProvider>
      {/* Your app components */}
    </NavbarProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

§ Using context to manipulate the state, you can revise the Navbar component accordingly.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import { NavbarContext } from "./NavbarContext";
import "./Navbar.css";

function Navbar() {
  const { navbarData, setNavbarData } = useContext(NavbarContext);
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState("Operational Overview");
  const location = useLocation();

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    navbarData.forEach((navItem) => {
      if (navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location, navbarData]);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        {/* Rest of your code */}
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

§ Where the JSON data for the navigation bar is received (typically after logging in), you can update the navbarData state using the setNavbarData function from the context.

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavbarContext } from "./NavbarContext";

function YourComponent() {
  const { setNavbarData } = useContext(NavbarContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch your JSON data from the backend
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/navbarData");
        const data = await response.json();
        setNavbarData(data); // Update the navbarData state with the fetched data
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [setNavbarData]);

  return <div>Your component content</div>;
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Using setNavbarData to update the navbarData state now causes a re-render of the Navbar component, which ultimately results in the updated data being displayed in the navigation bar.

React Router requires proper setup and the correct dependencies must be imported into your code. Make a note to verify these steps are completed.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer!! allright and lets say i dont have a backend connected yet and i want a dropdown swtitcher to switch between projects each option needs to include a NavbarData formatted content that i can inject into the NavbarData per project switch choice, how can i achieve that?